# servicemix change karaf password

Tags: java, authentication, activemq-classic, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I have a ServiceMix 5.3.2 instance running.
I have changed the karaf password changing the `etc/users.properties` file as following:

```
     karaf = karaf_2,_g_:admingroup
```

The problem is that when I use the activemq webconsol I have this exception in the log

```
    2016-06-21 12:07:43,296 | WARN  | .0.1:50986@61616 | TransportConnection              | ?                                   ? | 90 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.10.2 | Failed to add Connection ID:xxxxx-43557-1466503663160-1:1
    java.lang.SecurityException: User name [karaf] or password is invalid.
        at org.apache.activemq.security.JaasAuthenticationBroker.addConnection(JaasAuthenticationBroker.java:80)[90:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.addConnection(MutableBrokerFilter.java:102)[90:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConnection(TransportConnection.java:809)[90:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedTransportConnection.processAddConnection(ManagedTransportConnection.java:79)[90:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo.visit(ConnectionInfo.java:139)[90:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:334)[90:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:188)[90:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)[90:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:113)[90:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:270)[90:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)[90:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:214)[90:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)[90:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.2]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_80]
    Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: login failed
        at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.properties.PropertiesLoginModule.login(PropertiesLoginModule.java:127)
        at org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot.ProxyLoginModule.login(ProxyLoginModule.java:83)[karaf-jaas-boot.jar:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_80]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:762)[:1.7.0_80]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)[:1.7.0_80]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:690)[:1.7.0_80]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:688)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_80]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:687)[:1.7.0_80]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:595)[:1.7.0_80]
        at org.apache.activemq.security.JaasAuthenticationBroker.addConnection(JaasAuthenticationBroker.java:73)[90:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.10.2]
        ... 13 more
    2016-06-21 12:07:43,298 | WARN  | .0.1:50986@61616 | Service                          | ?                                   ? | 90 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.10.2 | Security Error occurred: User name [karaf] or password is invalid.
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'queueBrowser' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webconsole-query.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.activemq.web.QueueBrowseQuery]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: User name [karaf] or password is invalid.
    2016-06-21 12:07:43,304 | WARN  | qtp2055058088-69 | ServletHandler                   | ?                                   ? | 64 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.15.v20140411 |
```

I think I have to change the default password for the webconsole but I do not understand how to do this.
I tried to change the file `etc/org.apache.activemq.webconsole.cfg` but without success.
Thanks in advance